# Make multi API requests simultaneously

Tags: javascript

I have this code that returns the speed score of a website through google API. As sometimes the value is not correct, i read on a post, that is a good practice to make the request few times and then make the median of the score . How i can make multiple Api request simultaneously ?

I tried something like this

```
  function medianSpeed() {
    let values = [];
    function call() {
      return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          const speed = +json.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score;
          values.push(speed);
        });
    }
    const promise1 = call(),
      promise2 = call(),
      promise3 = call();
    const promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3];
    Promise.allSettled(promises).then(() => {
      return values;
    });
  }
```

now the thing is if i call `medianSpeed()` the code doesn't wait the end of `Promise.allSettled` it returns straight undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `medianSpeed()` add return before the call to `Promise.allSettled()`:

```
return Promise.allSettled(promises).then(() => {
      return values;
});
```

and when calling `medianSpeed()`, calc the median in `.then()` callback:

```
medianSpeed().then(values=>calcMedian(values))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue here is that `medianSpeed` isn't returning a promise, so there's nothing to wait for.

If you did `return Promise.allSettled...` and then did a `then` block after calling the function: `medianSpeed().then(values => {})` then you would get the values back.

I assume that the `url` variable is coming from somewhere else?

Comment: thank you. Yes, the URL is coming from somewhere else. I just trimmed the code to make it more readable